# Упростить код на C#

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Я сделал задачу из одного известного курса. Задача заключается в том, что у нас есть долг и мы можем оплатить его сразу либо по частям. Но условие состоит в том, что твой следующий платёж должен быть больше чём предыдущий. С самой задачей я справился, но смотря на код, думаю, что он очень запутанный и сложный.
Вот он:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int maxSum = 700;
        int payment = 0;
        int previousPayment = 0;
        int moneyToPay = 0; 

        while(maxSum != 0)
        {
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Введите сумму платежа");

                 payment = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                //previousPayment = payment;

                 moneyToPay = debt(payment, ref maxSum, ref previousPayment);

                if (moneyToPay == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            } while (false);

            if(moneyToPay == -1)
            {
                break;
            }

        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    static int debt(int a,ref int maxSum, ref int previousPayment)
    {
        if (a == maxSum) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Долг погашен");
            return maxSum = 0;
        }
        else if (a < maxSum)
        {
            int Debt = maxSum - a;
            if(a < previousPayment)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Вы должны оплатить сумму больше чём {0}", previousPayment);
                return -1;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Ваш долг составляет:{0}", Debt);
            maxSum = Debt;
            previousPayment = a;

            return Debt;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Долг погашен");
            Console.WriteLine("Переполнение составляет:{0}", a - maxSum);
            return maxSum = 0;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: в чем смысл делать `do{...}while(false)`?

Comment: @tCode, чтобы дополнительно обнулить переменную _maxSum_ которая по ref передается

Comment: @Grundy да, спасибо, уже понял, не увидел `ref maxSum`

Answer (score 6):

Ваш код действительно излишне запутан, большая часть ошибок типична для новичков, главное что вы САМИ нашли решение задачи, это уже огромный плюс.

Немного об ошибках.

- конструкция `do{...}while(false)` выполняется строго один раз, таким образом бесполезна и может быть удалена.
- `while(maxSum != 0)` осторожнее с использованием такого условия, т.к. цикл будет завершен строго при `maxSum == 0`, в данной задаче лучше было использовать условие `while(maxSum > 0)`.
- `static int debt(int a,ref int maxSum, ref int previousPayment)` очень хорошо, что вы смогли разобраться с передачей параметров по ссылке, но в данном случае было бы правильнее объявить `maxSum` и `previousPayment` приватными статическими полями класса, и обращаться к ним напрямую из метода. Это похоже на глобальные переменные, но только в пределах класса.
- немного запутана последовательность действий и видно, так сказать, ход ваших мыслей в процессе поиска. Нужно было еще раз посмотреть на найденное решение и постараться найти повторяющиеся моменты. Но это нормально для начала и придет с опытом, если не будете останавливаться на достигнутом.

Код можно изрядно сократить без ущерба "читаемости", например вот так:

```
void Main()
{
    int debt = 700;
    int lastPayment = 0;
    while(debt > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите сумму платежа");
        int payment = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        while(payment <= lastPayment)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Вы должны оплатить сумму больше чём {lastPayment}");
            payment = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        lastPayment = payment;
        debt -= payment;//debt = debt - payment на всякий случай
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Долг погашен");
    //как только долг стал меньше или равен 0, его модуль равен сумме переплаты, этим и воспользуемся.
    if(debt < 0)
        Console.WriteLine($"Переплата составляет:{-debt}");
}
```

Comment: стоило хотя бы перечислить ошибки

Comment: @Grundy вроде все перечислил, что можно подсказать кратко без лекции